# Swing in JmonkeyEngine (JME)

Tags: java, swing, jmonkeyengine

Is it possible to add Swing components in JME3 canvas? If it is possible please share the logic. 
I was able to achieve the other way round where I was able to integrate JME3 canvas in Swing.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way. What are you trying to achieve? There may be annother way

Comment: **I've never used it** but you may be able to get some functionality from a dynamic texture (not the same as swing, but you'll get something)

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't add Swing components to the JME3 canvas.